# JavaScript: convert [[a, b]] to [a, b]

Tags: javascript

I have - I thought simple problem - but I got:

```
[[a, b, ... ,n]]
```

and I would like transform it to

```
[a, b, ..., n]
```

Comment: Perhaps use `array = array[ 0 ]`?

Comment: Or perhaps [array = array.shift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arr = [[1, 2, 3, 4]];

console.log(arr.flat());
```

You can also use `Array.flat()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat